# NetSuite Saved search not showing records on Employee Centre dashboard

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I have created a saved search that works perfectly when I am running it from the admin account. However, when the intended users see it from their Employee Centre dashboard, they see reduced number of rows or no results. The search is about all the POs open in the system and is not checking for next approver as employee name. Ideally, it should have shown the same result to everyone having access to the report.
How do I make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used it in this context (to make records visible in the Employee Center), but there is an option to "Run Unrestricted" in the Results tab of the saves search definition page which might help.  The field help for this option is as follows:

> Check this box to make search results available to users who normally do not have permissions to see the underlying records.
>
> This option allows administrators to provide restricted users with limited access to specific records for a specific purpose. For example, an unrestricted saved search on leads could provide sales reps with the ability to identify potential duplicates before entering lead records.
>
> If you enable this option, the Edit and View columns of search results are blank for users in roles without the required permissions.